# Why I cannot cout the result?

Tags: c++

I have this error message:

```sh
Error   C2678   binary '^': no operator found which takes a left-hand
 operand of type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' 
(or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

with this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << 2 ^ 4;
}
```

could you help me with this code, please

- I use visual studio  2019

Comment: Operator precedence.  `<<` is higher than `^`, so `cout << 2 ^ 4` is equivalent to `(cout << 2) ^ 4`.   `cout << 2` outputs `2` and gives result that is of type `std::ostream &` (referring to `cout`).    The `^` then has the same effect as `std::cout ^ 4` which is invalid.   To get the result you expect, do `cout << (2 ^ 4)`.

Answer (score 4):

`operator<<` has higher precedence than `operator ^`, so `cout << 2 ^ 4;` is interpreted as `(cout << 2) ^ 4;`. `(cout << 2)` returns `cout` itself, which can't be used as operand of `operator ^`.

Change the code to

```
cout << (2 ^ 4);
```

Comment: Note: it's not going to compute exponent

Comment: The result was 6 instead of 16 when I wrote this code

Comment: @hagaraziz Yes since it's a [bitwise XOR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << (2 ^ 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I actually tried to write the code as cout<<(2^4); but the result was 6